# Js oop design pattern function difference ?

Tags: javascript, oop

type 1

```
  this.toString = function () {

  };
```

type 2

```
   myPublicMethod: function () {

    }
```

type3

```
  var myPrivateMethod = function () {

    }
```

type4

```
Y.store.basket = (function () {

})();
```

i am studying JS oop design pattern , i have this all kind of function which is confuse me , what the difference btw this all this function , type 2 and type 3 which is public and private ?

Comment: They have really nothing in common except for involving a function expression. Some of the snippets you posted are not even syntactically valid in usual contexts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. This is a method inside a constructor function. So all the objects created with this constructor will have that method.
2. You'll see this kind of public method in module pattern. In the module pattern, you will have private variables and private methods but you will only expose some methods by returning an object containing those methods.
3. It's a private method that you'll see in the module pattern.
4. This is a module. You can keep private methods and private variables. And return an object. All the methods in that returned object will be public.

Comment: …or they could be anything else. Yes, the design patterns that you mention involve the things the OP posted, but you cannot make this connection the other way round.